# ASP.NET MVC: Model binding half an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have a form to add a new user with a few checkboxes for user roles. I have a model in my action called User which has the following properties:

```
public string Username { get; set; }
public string Password { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<UserRole> Roles { get; set; }
```

Inside the UserRole class I have two properties:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
```

In my form I can successfully bind to Username and Password no problem by giving the input names 'Username' and 'Password'. When the page initially loads the user role details are loaded and so all I need to pass back in is the Id because this is what the service needs to associate a user with a user role.

I thought I could do this the simple way by giving each checkbox the value of the role Id and passing that in to Roles therefore partially completing the roles class and leaving the Name field of the role object blank. An example checkbox looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="addUserAdministrator" name="Roles.Id" value="@Model.Roles.Where(role => role.Name == "Administrator").Select(role => role.Id).First()" class="css-checkbox"/>
```

However this never populates the Roles collection and it is always null. Is there a way of doing this or will I need to do the long winded way of passing in a list on ints and creating the model in the action?

EDIT:

My action looks like this:

```
public RedirectToRouteResult Add(User user)
```

Comment: are you usinf form collection to retrive values from checkbox

Comment: I've updated my question, I'm trying to bind to that object

Comment: The action is expecting a User object, but you appear to be passing in a Role, can you post the whole form code?

Comment: As said in my post the other form items are called Username and Password which bind straight to those properties on the user object. Roles.Id would make sense because Id is a property of the UserRole class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you can bind a collection of primitive type - int in your case

```
 public IList<Int> Roles { get; set; } //role id's here
```

using

```
<input type="checkbox" id="addUserAdministrator" name="Roles"
```

or if you want Roles collection you should explicitly specify an indexing to your collections. Read [this article](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx). It's better to use non-sequential indexing (e.g. using Guid.NewGuid()) in case of gaps between selected items in list on the form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="Roles.Index" value="@(GuidIndexForThisRow)" />
<input type="checkbox" name="Roles[@(GuidIndexForThisRow)].Id" value="1" />
```

Comment: I tried your second suggestion but the problem came when I selected 2 or more checkboxes and submitted those, only one (the first one) was ever bound to the object

Comment: Are you using differnet guid for each pair of hidden\checkbox? It shoud be the same in pair but unique between pairs.

Comment: I couldn't even get it to bind to Roles with your way of using a guid for hidden/checkbox pair. It will bind if I explicitly set name as Roles[0].Id but otherwise it is always null

Comment: can you show the html markup you get using my second suggestion? link to screenshot\file etc. It should work. You don't set Roles[0].Id, Roles[1].Id. But [name=Roles.Index,value=Guid1][name=Roles[Guid1].Id,value1] | [name=Roles.Index,value=Guid2][name=Roles[Guid2].Id,value2] etc....

Comment: I've decided to go with your first suggestion, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

When I use Collections with Razor, I solve this way: I use a for block to create a new checkbox, textbox or whatever you want to display with the index of the collection, 'cause when you call a controller method, the model binds your Collection values based in index.

Try this:
1. Create a boolean field into your Roles ViewModel, to know when a role was selected.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Username)
@Html.PasswordBoxFor(model => model.Password, new { value = Model.Password })

<ul id="roles">
@for (int I = 0; I < Model.Roles.Count(); ++I)
{
    <li>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Roles[I].ID)
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => Model.Roles[I].RoleSelected)
        @Model.Roles[I].Name
    </li>
}
</ul>
```

Try something like this.

Comment: I'm not sure this would work for me because I have a model for loading data initially and a different model for passing data to the action, since these have different information

Comment: This way will bind your View according Roles collection. Whatever you put a value into initialization or change this value, that loop will display your current content.